# See if index is contained within a slice object

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, slice, sequence, membership

I have an enum like this:

```
class AgeCategory(Enum):
    Child = slice(None, 16)
    YoungAdult = slice(16, 25)
    ...
    Old = slice(85, None)
```

It basically provides a range of ages (in years) which go in each category.

I would like a function to check which age range a certain value corresponds to. This was my idea:

```
def get_category(age: int) -> AgeCategory:
    for age_range in AgeCategory:
         if age in age_range.value #check if it's in the slice for that enum
             return age_range
    else:
        assert False, "unreachable"
```

However `assert 5 in slice(1,10)` fails. OFC I could do something like:

```
s: slice = age_range.value
if s.start <= age < s.stop: #bounds check
    return age_range
```

But that ignores the step argument and feels like reinventing the wheel a bit.

---

What's a pythonic way to express these age ranges? They are used as slices like this:

```
ya_data = np.sum(some_data[AgeCategory.YoungAdult])
```

Comment: Sadly slice() doesn't return an iterable and as mentioned in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=slice#slice) itertools.islice() returns an iterable but will not work with NumPy as it returns an iterable of the elements and not indexes, you can try ```if age in list(range(age_range.start, age_range.stop, age_range.step))``` but you have to take care of None in the start and stop

Comment: A `slice` is just a container for start, stop, step values.  It doesn't provide much functionality.I'd make a `arange` from it, or maybe `list(range())` and test that.

Answer (score 1):

In your case it is not so much important, but this should be faster than iterating when working with large slices:

```
a_slice = slice(4, 15, 3)
def is_in_slice(a_slice, idx):
    if idx < a_slice.start or idx >= a_slice.stop:
        return False
    step = a_slice.step if a_slice.step else 1
    if (idx - a_slice.start) % step == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
test_array = np.where([is_in_slice(a_slice, idx) for idx in range(20)])[0]
print(test_array)
```

```
[ 4  7 10 13]
```

And test for very big slice:

```
a_big_slice = slice(0, 1_000_000_000_000, 5)
print(is_in_slice(a_big_slice, 999_000_000_005))
print(is_in_slice(a_big_slice, 999_000_000_004))
```

```
True
False
```

Answer (score 1):

With a sample slice:

```
In [321]: child=slice(None,16,4)
```

I was thinking of expanding it to a list or array.  But `arange` can't handle the `None`:

```
In [323]: np.arange(child.start,child.stop,child.step)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-323-b2d245f287ff>", line 1, in <module>
    np.arange(child.start,child.stop,child.step)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

`np.r_` can.  Here the numpy developers have gone to all the work of translating all the slice options:

```
In [324]: np.r_[child]
Out[324]: array([ 0,  4,  8, 12])
In [325]: 3 in _
Out[325]: False
In [327]: 4 in __
Out[327]: True
```

It may not be fastest, but appears to be most general purpose approach - with out a lot work on your part.